# Parametric Hypercube

Tags: python, grasshopper, parametric-equations

Looking to describe in 4-dimensional hypercube.  I have located this parametric equation [via wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercone):

[image: parametric equation]

I am failing to translate this into something useful for me.  I have attempted to define is functions of x, y, z, and w. So far I am here:

```
let a = theta
let b = phi

x (u,v) =  t*s*cos(a)*cos(b)
y (u,v) =  t*s*cos(a)*sin(b)
z (u,v) =  t*s*sin(a)
w (u,v) =  t
```

Do I need the point of the cone (singularity) to be at (0,0,0,0) ?
I am hoping to implement this with rhino/grasshopper/python. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The implicit equation is:

```
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -w^2 = 0
```

Comment: Do you want to project the 4d cube into 3d space? Your equation needs a 4d engine to draw the w axis in.